# MySQL 5.5 PPA Trustworthy?

Tags: ppa, mysql

I found this PPA which features MySQL 5.5 (alongside php 5.3.8 packages..):

https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ppa

Seems to be working fine on my 11.10 Ubuntu, ut I can't find anything on the person/group behind the release.

Is this PPA trustworthy? Do you know anything about "Nathan Rennie-Waldock"? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: This is a pretty tough question for anyone who doesn't know Nathan Rennie-Waldock, how are we supposed to answer this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately it is going to be your choice whether you wan't to use the PPA. The LP user in question does not seem to be a member of any teams but honestly I see little value in someone going through all the time of creating a PPA, Signing the CoC and packaging MySQL just to try and distribute something other than what it purports to be.

You could download the official MySQL 5.5 release and grab the PPA's package take them apart and do checksum.

Comment: Yes, my question was more about whether this guy knows what his doing, and less about him trying to sneak anything into that package.

Comment: I can vouch for him being trustworthy. I've known him for a few years.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it if you like. It's safe. MySQL and PHP are both built from the original source using the packaging from Debian. If you don't trust it, don't use it. I run those same builds on several live sites and dev servers.

Comment: Still you should add some trust by f.e. getting your GPG keys signed by couple of people and establish your web of trust or becoming Ubuntu Member.  So far it's hard to tell even if you are the same Nathan Rennie-Waldock here and on the launchpad.